# Add second image to standard UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Is there a way to add a second image to the right of a table row while still using a standard subview cell?  I would like to take advantage of the standardization of the subview but add a second picture to the far right.

Basically, I want a circular profile picture to the left as in Instagram and a separate photo to the right of the text.

Here is my code for the table cell that works:

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"ListPrototypeCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Configure the cell...
    tableItem *tableItem = [self.tableItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.textLabel.text = tableItem.itemName;
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = tableItem.itemSub;

    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"pic.jpg"];
CGSize itemSize = CGSizeMake(40, 40);
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(itemSize, NO, UIScreen.mainScreen.scale);
        CGRect imageRect = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, itemSize.width, itemSize.height);
        [cell.imageView.image drawInRect:imageRect];
        cell.imageView.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
         cell.imageView.layer.masksToBounds=YES;
        cell.imageView.layer.cornerRadius=20.0;
        cell.imageView.frame = CGRectMake(20, 20, 500, 50);


        return cell;
```

Can I add a separate image in here without having to create a whole custom cell? Here is look I am going for:

two pictures[image: pic]

Comment: Just use `addSubview`.  You do need to consider where you place it, of course, and know to remove it if the cell is recycled and used where the extra image isn't needed.

Comment: would I add something like UIImageView *rightimage;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:rightimage];

Comment: Well, you'd need to actually create the image view first, and set its frame.

Comment: as in rightimage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(225.0,0.0,80.0,45.0)]; ?

Comment: Something like that.

Comment: Probably best to tag it, so you can find it later.

Answer (score -2):

You'll have to basically make a custom UITableViewCell in this case.  The standard UITableViewCell just has the one image view on the left.

When you create the custom UITableViewCell (it can be done in the Storyboard), be sure to give it an identifier.  Then place your two UIImageViews within the custom cell and give them each a unique tag.  Then you can call up the UIImageViews based on their tags:

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"ListPrototypeCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    UIImageView *img1 = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:1];
    UIImageView *img2 = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:2];

    // Set the images of img1 and img2

}
```

Comment: Some of it, but not all.  I'll expand on my answer

Comment: do the cell.textlabel and cell.imageview.layer.cornerRadius and so forth references still work or do I have to custom create all these?

Comment: I would create these as well and give them tags and reference them as I'm doing with the UIImageViews

Comment: Using tags to identify views in the cell like this  is a code smell.